# Shiny Server - how to use session$onSessionEnded()

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm trying to track user activity as they go through my shiny app.  I have functions placed at specific locations which write lines to a temporary file.  What I want is to have a function which is called when the user session ends.

According to the documentation:

```
> ?session
> onSessionEnded(callback)  
      Registers a function to be called after the client has disconnected. Returns a function that can be called with no arguments to cancel the registration.
```

I tried to use this:

```
session$onSessionEnded(function(x){
  a = read_csv(shinyActivityTmpFile_000)
  write_csv(a,'C:\\Users\\xxxx\\Desktop\\test.csv')
})
```

But nothing happened.  `shinyActivityTmpFile_000` is a global file reference.  As the user clicks buttons and does stuff, the app is writing out to this file in a CSV format.  I'm just trying to move it from temporary storage to permanent storage.  Ultimately I'd like the function to write it to a database but for testing I'm just trying to get a function that will run when the app is closed.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Try with no arguments with the function in `onSessionEnded` : `function() {...}`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Hi I don't know how you construct the `shinyActivityTmpFile` file, but for using `onSessionEnded` you can look at this exemple, it write in a file the datetime when an app is launched and when the app is closed :

```
library("shiny")
ui <- fluidPage(
  "Nothing here"
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # This code will be run once per user
  users_data <- data.frame(START = Sys.time())

  # This code will be run after the client has disconnected
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    users_data$END <- Sys.time()
    # Write a file in your working directory
    write.table(x = users_data, file = file.path(getwd(), "users_data.txt"),
                append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

If you use a server with authentication, you can retrieve the username with :

```
users_data <- data.frame(USERS = session$user, START = Sys.time())
```

Comment: Is there any way to specify only one session to do something when the session ends. For example    
        
        `session$onSessionEnded( function(){
        if(userID==1)  cat("Do Something Wild")  }) `

Comment: @Jordan please check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Based on @Victorp answer and reply to the comment about arguments to `session$onSessionEnded`. It is possible to add an argument to the function using a default parameter:

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # This code will be run once per user
  users_data <- data.frame(USERS = session$user, START = Sys.time())

  # This code will be run after the client has disconnected
  session$onSessionEnded(function(userID = users_data$USERS) {
      if(userID==1){
          users_data$END <- Sys.time()
          # Write a file in your working directory
          write.table(x = users_data, file = file.path(getwd(), "users_data.txt"),
                      append = TRUE, row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE, sep = "\t")
      }
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```